# Title menu not appearing in my hamburger html page

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

Good day,

I have designed an hamburger html page. My title 'domoos mobile' is only displayed when the hamburger is 'unfolded' (I'm not sure if I'm using the correct word). See pictures below :

[image]
[image]

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here and why my title does not display properly.

I hope my question is understandable and will be helpful to other programmers as well. This is my first mobile design, so I do also hope you will be indulgent with me ;)

Thanks for your help.

*Contents of the html page :*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Domoos mobile </title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <!--Using jQuery and jQuery UI for display effects--> 
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <!--Using the hamburger menu display code--> 
    <script src="scripts/hamburger.js"></script> 
    <!--Using Media Queries, if the viewport is smaller than 700px use another stylesheet--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/hamburger.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_hamburger.css" />
</head> 
<body>
    <!--This wrapping container is used to get the width of the whole content--> 
    <div id="container">
    <!--The Hamburger Button in the Header--> 
    <header>
        <div id="hamburger"> 
        <div></div> 
        <div></div> 
        <div></div> 
    </div> 
    </header>
    <!--The mobile navigation Markup hidden via css--> 
    <nav> 
        <ul>
            <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">menuitem 1</a></li> -->
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--The Layer that will be layed over the content 
    so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown--> 
    <a name="top"></a>
    <div id="contentLayer"></div> 
    <!--The content of the site--> 
    <div id="content">      
        <div id="tag_domoos_title">
        <p>Domoos mobile</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

*Contents of the CSS file (mystyle_hamburger.css):*

```
#tag_domoos_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 110%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 101px;
    color:black;
    z-index:10;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#date{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 101px;
    color:blue;
}
#time{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 103px;
    left: 101px;
    color:blue;
}

#tag_sunrise_sunset{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 107px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_condition{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 148px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_conditions{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 168px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_icon {
  position: relative;
}

#meteo_icon img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
}

#meteo_forecast{
    font-family:Arial;  
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:434px;
    width:870px;
    top:200px;
    position: absolute;
}

#meteo_forecast_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;    
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;    
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;   
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}


#domoos_logo{
position: relative; 
}

#domoos_logo img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
}

#lorem{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 700px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete code? It doesn't look like your screenshot. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpKvpP

Comment: I don't know how codepen.io is working but we need to load as well the javascript jquery-2.1.3.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js and hamburger.js. Maybe I'm wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

well dear I see that you started wrong...why won't you start with bootstrap? there are some good templates there. you can use them for dropdown menus, input for search box and so on you can use this link to see some templates: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

[image]

```
    enter code here

I also added you something I used from bootstrap site with this code:
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```